# Completions of Global Field are Local Fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory, local-field

Neukirch's book defines a global field as a finite extension of $\mathbb Q$ or a finite extension of $\mathbb{F}_p(x)$ for $p$ prime, and a local field as a field that admits some discrete valuation $v$ with which $K$ is complete and has finite residue class field. Neukirch then states that the completion of a global field is always a local field.

However, I am having to difficulties:

1. I don't know how to prove that every valuation of a global field is discrete;
2. I can prove that a completion of a global field has finite residue class field provided the following fact (that I can't prove) is true:

"Let $L/K$ be a finite extension. Then $\hat{L}/\hat{K}$ is also a finite extension, where $\hat{L}$ and $\hat{K}$ is the completion of the fields $L$ and $K$ with respect to some valuation $v\colon L\to \mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$".

Comment: (1) is called Ostrowski's theorem: it says that every absolute value on a global field is either archimediean, trivial or a $\mathfrak p$-adic absolute value for some prime ideal $\mathfrak p$. For (2), let $L = K(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_n)$. Can you show that $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$ generated $\widehat L$ over $\widehat K$?

Comment: Do you have some reference to Ostrowski's theorem?

And I think I proved (2), as follows: suppose $L=K\alpha_1+\cdots+K\alpha_n$. Let $\beta\in \hat{L}$, and let $(\beta_k)\to \beta$ with each $\beta_k\in L$. We write $\beta_k=c_{k1}\alpha_1+\cdots+c_{kn}\alpha_n$, and observe that $\hat{K}\alpha_1+\cdots+\hat{K}\alpha_n$ is finite-dimensional over $\hat{K}$, hence its norm is equivalent to maximum norm, from which we conclude that each $(c_{kj})\to c_j\in \hat{K}$. Then we see that $\beta=c_1\alpha_1+\cdots+c_n\alpha_n\in \hat{K}\alpha_1+\cdots+\hat{K}\alpha_n$. Does it seem correct?